# Including images in survey monkey

Tags: python, json, api, surveymonkey

I am trying to include an image as a survey question and it gives be the below error,

surveymonty.exceptions.SurveyMontyAPIError: {"error": {"docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", "message": "Failed to validate field 'headings' list schema: additional properties not defined by 'properties' are not allowed in field '_data'", "id": "1002", "name": "Bad Request", "http_status_code": 400}}

I am using the below JSON code,

```
payload ={
    "headings": 
    [
            {
            "heading": "This is a monkey",
            "image":    {
                "img_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs/master/images/presentation.png"
                    }
             }
        ],
    "position": 4,
    "family": "presentation",
    "subtype": "descriptive_text"
    }
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Please don't page text as an image. Please copy-paste the actual text itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `image` subtype, the payload should look more like:

```
{
    "headings": [{
        "heading": "This is a monkey",
        "image": {
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs/master/images/presentation.png"
        }
    }],
    "position": 4,
    "family": "presentation",
    "subtype": "image"
}
```

Comment: How can I add "answers" field in the code above for the "image" type question?

Comment: payload ={ "headings": [ 
{ "heading": "What monkey is this?", "image": { "url": "<jpeg link>" } } ], "position": 1, "family": "single_choice", "subtype": "vertical",    "answers": {
        "choices":[
            {
                "text": "Capuchin"
            },
            {
                "text": "Mandrill"
            },
        ],
        "other":[
                {
                    "text": "Other",
                    "num_chars": 100,
                    "num_lines": 3
                }
        ]
    } }